# Replace SQL - Reemplazar caracteres especiales SQL con funcion

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito reemplazar unos caracteres especiales usando SQL 2008, para eso genere una función.

Esta es la parte -sql- que donde se hace el reemplazo:

```
   set @raw = replace(replace(@raw,'&lt;br /&gt; * ','<br/>*'),'&amp;nbsp;',' ')
```

Este es el resultado:

> Politica de cancelacion en base al huso horario del
>   destino:<br /> <br />* Cancelando desde 18/10/2016 a las
>   00:00:00 hasta 18/10/2016 a las 00:59:59: 0  USD <br />*   Desde
>   estos momentos hasta la fecha de inicio de viaje 20/10/2016 00:00 : 1
>   noche(s)

Como puedo hacer para reemplazar la parte del texto que viene con esos caracteres especiales : `&lt;br /&gt; &lt;br /&gt;`

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si deseas en algún momento, recuperar esa información de la base de datos puedes realizarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
SET @raw = 
  Replace(
    Replace(
      Replace(@raw,'&','&amp;'),
    '<', '&lt;'),
  '>', '&gt;')
```

De esta forma se codifica y cuando la recuperes en el cliente la decodificas y se mantiene la integridad de la información.

Si deseas reemplazarla con algo más o simplemente quitarla ya sería que los reemplaces con el texto de tu preferencia.